# numpy default value for dtype out-of-range

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dtype

Works:

```
import numpy as np
dtype_L1 = [('ts', np.float32), ('s_id', np.uint16)]

arr = np.array((1,2), dtype=dtype_L1)
arr
array((1., 2), dtype=[('ts', '<f4'), ('s_id', '<u2')]) ##### CORRECT
```

Huups: Due to the `unit16` declaration the `-2` is interpreted as `65534`:

```
arr2 = np.array((1,-2), dtype=dtype_L1)
arr2
array((1., 65534), dtype=[('ts', '<f4'), ('s_id', '<u2')]) ##### -2 interpreted wrongly
```

Is there a method in `numpy` which is doing something like a **dtype check** to see if all inputs are matching the [standard ranges](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html)?

So it would check if the `unit16` field is an *"Unsigned integer (0 to 65535)"* and would otherwise set a default value?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple functions for checking datatype ranges, see [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html#overflow-errors). There are `np.iinfo` and `np.finfo` for integer and float datatypes, respectively. For example:

```
info = np.iinfo(np.uint16)

info
>>> iinfo(min=0, max=65535, dtype=uint16)
```

And `min` and `max` attributes can be accessed as `info.min` etc.